# Getting layer EPSG in ArcMap using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, arcmap, arcgis-10.1

How do i get my layer EPSG with Python in ArcMap 10.1?

It needs to return a integer.

something like this:

```
layerEPSG = arcpy.getActiveLayerEpsg()
```

Here is some context:

```
    insrs = arcpy.SpatialReference(layerEPSG)
    outsrs = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)
    newcoord = arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(x,y),insrs).projectAs(outsrs).lastPoint
```

Actually i needed the dataframe factorycode which is this:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
projectEPSG = df.spatialReference.factoryCode
```

Comment: A "layer" doesn't have a coordinate system, per se, since it's the map canvas that defines the common spatial reference. Each layer has a source reference, and many sources have a defined SpatialReference, but custom SRs might not have an equivalent EPSG factory code. An older build of ArcGIS certainly wouldn't reflect newer EPSG values.

Comment: Show us how you create the layer object

Comment: [You commented that you received an error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263145/getting-layer-epsg-in-arcmap-using-arcpy#comment417892_263148) - what was it?

Comment: You appear to have done a Describe on a basemap layer name, not a data source. You'd likely get the info you need from a layer, but you'd need to access it correctly. See the documentation.

Comment: i think you are right. i tested another layer and it worked. Is there a way to get the spatialreference from a basemap layer? or map sr or project sr...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use arcpy.Describe

```
insrs = arcpy.Describe(<the layer>).spatialReference.factoryCode
```

Comment: Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: DescribeData: Method spatialReference does not exist

Comment: hmm, should be avail in 10.1 afaik.
try to break it up like:
   desc = arcpy.Describe(<feature class>)
   srid_name = desc.spatialReference.name

Comment: same error as before

Comment: @JoséGabriel Please edit your question to show a code snippet that starts with `import arcpy` and shows how you tested this answer, and any error message that you received.

Comment: >>> import arcpy
... desc = arcpy.Describe("World Imagery") 
... srid_name = desc.spatialReference.name
... print "name: {}".format(srid_name)
... 
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
AttributeError: DescribeData: Method spatialReference does not exist